# Factorise numbers (Erlang)

Tags: function, recursion, erlang

Im looking to factorise a number based on Head or Middle recursion in Erlang. The function is called fact and takes 1 parameter, fact/1. The result will return a list of the numbers that are factors of the number.

24 returns the following: [1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24]

Does anyone have any ideas how I would go about this?

Comment: you do not have any ideas for the implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I propose you this solution. I search first the decomposition in prime factors, and then build the list of divisors. I think it should be more efficient in average.

```
divlist(N) -> automult([1|decomp(N)]).

decomp(N) when is_integer(N), (N > 0) -> 
    lists:reverse(decomp(N,[],2)).

decomp(N,R,I) when I*I > N -> [N|R];
decomp(N,R,I) when (N rem I) =:= 0 -> decomp(N div I,[I|R],I);
decomp(N,R,2) -> decomp(N,R,3);
decomp(N,R,I) -> decomp(N,R,I+2).

automult(L=[H]) when is_number(H)-> L;
automult([H|Q]) when is_number(H)->
    L1 = automult(Q),
    L2 = [H*X || X <- L1],
    lists:usort([H|L1]++L2).
```

The solutions proposed by @Zoukaye and @P_A and mine give the same result, but both of their solutions have a complexity of O(n). My proposal is more complex to evaluate since it is divided in 2 parts. The search or prime decomposition is majored by 0(log(n)), and the second part depend of the result of the first one, the interesting point is that it cannot be the worse case for both part:

- if a number has many prime factor, the search of them is fast, and the composition of all divider takes longer.
- if a number has few (1) prime factor, the search take longer, but the composition is short.

Last remark, @Zoukaye uses an intermediate list of integer. if you intend to use this for looooong integer, it is a bad idea since you will crash for lack of memory just building this list.

I made a performance test comparing the solutions where I create a list of N random numbers less than Max, evaluate the whole execution time for each solution, verify that they are equivalent and return times. The result is

10 000 tests for number less than 10 000:

mine: 63ms, P_A: 788ms, Zoukaye: 1383ms

10 000 tests for number less than 100 000:

mine: 80ms, P_A: 9240ms, Zoukaye: 13594ms

10 000 tests for number less than 1000 000:

mine: 105ms, P_A: 101001ms, Zoukaye: 137145ms

Here is the code I used:

```
-module (test).

-compile((export_all)).


test(Nbtest,Max) ->
    random:seed(erlang:now()),
    L = [random:uniform(Max) || _ <- lists:seq(1,Nbtest)],
    F1 = fun() -> [{X,divlist(X)} || X <- L] end,
    F2 = fun() -> [{X,fact_comp(X)} || X <- L] end,
    F3 = fun() -> [{X,fact_rec(X)} || X <- L] end,
    {T1,R} = timer:tc(F1),
    {T2,R} = timer:tc(F2),
    {T3,R} = timer:tc(F3),
    {T1,T2,T3}.


% Method1
divlist(N) -> automult([1|decomp(N)]).

decomp(N) when is_integer(N), (N > 0) -> 
    lists:reverse(decomp(N,[],2)).

decomp(N,R,I) when I*I > N -> [N|R];
decomp(N,R,I) when (N rem I) =:= 0 -> decomp(N div I,[I|R],I);
decomp(N,R,2) -> decomp(N,R,3);
decomp(N,R,I) -> decomp(N,R,I+2).

automult(L=[H]) when is_number(H)-> L;
automult([H|Q]) when is_number(H)->
    L1 = automult(Q),
    L2 = [H*X || X <- L1],
    lists:usort([H|L1]++L2).

% Method 2
fact_comp(N) ->
    if N > 0  ->
         [ V || V <- lists:seq(1, N div 2), N rem V =:= 0 ] ++ [ N ];
       N < 0 -> 
         Na = 0 - N,
         [ V || V <- lists:seq(1, Na div 2), Na rem V =:= 0 ] ++ [ Na ];
       N =:= 0 -> []
    end.


% Method 3
fact_rec(N) ->
    fact_rec(N, 1, []).

fact_rec(N, I, Acc) when I =< trunc(N/2) ->
    case N rem I of
        0 -> fact_rec(N, I+1, [I | Acc]);
        _ -> fact_rec(N, I+1, Acc)
    end;
fact_rec(N, _I, Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc) ++ [N].
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
-module(fact).
-export([fact_rec/1]).

fact_rec(N) ->
    fact_rec(N, 1, []).

fact_rec(N, I, Acc) when I =< trunc(N/2) ->
    case N rem I of
        0 -> fact_rec(N, I+1, [I | Acc]);
        _ -> fact_rec(N, I+1, Acc)
    end;
fact_rec(N, _I, Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc) ++ [N].
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
fact_comp(N) ->
    if N > 0  ->
         [ V || V <- lists:seq(1, N div 2), N rem V =:= 0 ] ++ [ N ];
       N < 0 -> 
         Na = 0 - N,
         [ V || V <- lists:seq(1, Na div 2), Na rem V =:= 0 ] ++ [ Na ];
       N =:= 0 -> []
    end.
```